# Process.Start will not work when invoked from Task Scheduler on server

Tags: c#, process.start

Good Day

I am having issues using `Process.Start()` when I deploy to a server.
As usual "It works fine on my machine", which does not help.  On the server though, when using task manager to kick off the program, I can see in the log the `process.start` method is called.
But the external program never launches.
If I run the external program with the same working directory, program, and args on the command line everything works as expected.

Here is my code if anyone can help.

```
<add key="StartProgram" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinTask\bin\TaskExec.exe"/>
<add key="StartUpDirectory" value="D:\DS3\WeatherDownLoad\RunDownload"/>
<add key="Args" value="ProdDownLoadWeather.rob"/>


Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = settings["StartProgram"];
process.StartInfo.Arguments = settings["Args"];
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = settings["StartUpDirectory"];
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: if you change this line `process.StartInfo.FileName = settings["StartProgram"];` to the following `process.StartInfo.FileName = @settings["StartProgram"];` what happens do the same for the following `<add key="StartUpDirectory" value="@D:\DS3\WeatherDownLoad\RunDownload/>` also does the Server have a `D:\DS3 path as well as a `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Not sure if typo just here but your second line is missing an end quotation after the word "RunDownload"

Comment: Those 2 paths exist on the server.  And I forgot to mention the account on the task manager is a member of the Administrators security group.

Comment: Is the account being used in the scheduled task the currently logged in user? I ask to make sure you gave that user batch permissions if they are not the logged in user.

Also, if your server is running on 2008, the scheduled task needs a working directory supplied in the actual scheduled task or you may run into oddball issues like this.

Comment: I have marked the task to run whether the user was logged in or not.  The server is running 2012 R2.  I can not find anywhere to enter a working directory.

Comment: What _user_ is the scheduled task running under?  When you run the program at the command line, it is running under whatever credentials you have logged on with.  With the task scheduler, it runs under whatever credentials are set up with the task.  Does that user account have the necessary privileges to properly execute the exe?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not doing anything incorrect.  A third party component requires it's own desktop.  So when I was using Remote Desktop it could not open another desktop.  Thanks for trying to help.